# EL variable in JSF ResourceBundle

Tags: jsf, localization, internationalization, seam, resourcebundle

i read somewhere (don't find it anymore) that i can use EL Expresions in the resource bundle and then use it without changes in  *.xhtml files.

```
some.text=#{someBean.stepsLeft} more
```

to switch the position of the variable in different languages. But actually it wont work. 
I can use Interpolator class to handle the parsing or add some.text.before some.text.after and let one of them empty. I would prefer it to use it without interpolator.interpolate() if possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JSF resourcebundles does by default not resolve EL. It however by default supports [`MessageFormat` API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) in combination with [`<h:outputFormat>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputFormat.html) and [`<f:param>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/param.html).

```
some.text = {0} more
```

with

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{i18n['some.text']}">
    <f:param value="#{someBean.stepsLeft}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

You can even explicitly make it a `number` type so that e.g. `1000` will be displayed as `1,000` or `1.000` depending on the view locale.

```
some.text = {0,number} more
```

For more formatting options see thus the [`MessageFormat` API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

Comment: as fast as it could be. Thank you again. What would JSF stackoverflow be without you ;)