# JSF 2.0 : Runtime variables in property files

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

All text in our app is read from properties file
e.g.

```
<h:outputText value="#{text['fill.form']}"/>
```

text is a resource bundle that resolves to Text.properties.

```
Text.properties
fill.form=Please fill out the form below
```

There are other instance where we need run time variables inside the properties
e.g.

```
welcome.user=Welcome #{name.last}, #{name.first} to our site
```

name is a managed bean whose properties first and last get resolved at run time.

However the first name and last name are not resolved at run time. Instead the user sees the following

```
Welcome #{name.last}, #{name.first} to our site
```

Any solutions to this problem?
Should I write a custom EL resolver to resolve the text from the properties and also any run time properties inside of it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [outputFormat](http://wikis.sun.com/display/g11nhome/Checklist+for+Internationalization+using+JSF#ChecklistforInternationalizationusingJSF-OutputwithJSP) tag and [resource bundle compound messages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageFormat.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EL variable in JSF ResourceBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547136/el-variable-in-jsf-resourcebundle)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use `h:outputFormat` to accomplish this.  In your example, you might do this:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{text['welcome.user']}">
    <f:param value="#{name.last}"/>
    <f:param value="#{name.first}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

For this to work, you need to change your welcome message to this:

```
welcome.user=Welcome {0}, {1} to our site
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do this. The properties file is created by content editors using a content management tool and they may add new params without our knowledge. We can't change the code to keep up with the new params added. I am close to getting this done using a custom resolver.